# How can I debug an SQL Server data issue that I can't seem to reproduce in any test environment?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, debugging

I have a stored procedure in production that does 2 things. It updates one table and then inserts a record into another. The first step (the update) seems to occur but we've found instances by examining the data where the second step did not occur. I have looked at the data and confirmed that it is not a data issue. I've confirmed that the queries return the appropriate data in order to ensure that the queries complete and in normal circumstances both should execute. I don't know if perhaps there is some sort of performance issue ... or blocking issue that is occurring on the second step that prevents that  step from occurring.

The error handling for the stored procedure is as follows.

```
BEGIN TRY  

BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

 -- perform update to data

 -- insert record into second table. 


 IF ( @@ERROR = 0 AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0 )  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  

 END TRY  
 BEGIN CATCH  

   IF ( @@TRANCOUNT > 0 )  
   BEGIN   
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
   END  

   DECLARE @WebSafeErrorId INT;  
   EXEC dbo.spErrorInsert @WebSafeErrorId OUTPUT, 'Proc';  

   -- Reraise the error back to the client.  
   IF ( @WebSafeErrorId != 0 )   
   BEGIN   
      DECLARE @Error VARCHAR(20);  
      SET @Error = CAST( @WebSafeErrorId AS VARCHAR(20) );  
      RAISERROR( @Error, 11, 1 );  
   END  
   ELSE  
   BEGIN  
      RAISERROR( 'An error has occurred but there is no error to log.', 11, 1 );  
   END   

END CATCH;
```

Surely if an error occurred in this procedure that cause the insert to not occur it would be logged and then raised. The code for spErrorInsert is below ...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spErrorInsert]  
@ReturnErrorId INT OUTPUT  
, @ErrorSourceType VARCHAR(4) = NULL  
, @ParentErrorId INT = NULL  
, @StackTrace VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL  
AS  

SET NOCOUNT ON;  
--SET XACT_ABORT ON;  

-- Will indicate an error was not logged.  
SET @ReturnErrorID = 0;   

DECLARE  
  @ErrorSource VARCHAR(200)  
  , @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX)  
  , @ComposedErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX)  
  , @ErrorLine INT  
  , @ErrorSeverity INT  
  , @ErrorState INT  
  , @ErrorNumber INT;  

 SET @ErrorSource = ERROR_PROCEDURE();  
 SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();  
 SET @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE();  
 SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();  
 SET @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  
 SET @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();  
 SET @ComposedErrorMessage = 'Message: Error occurred in procedure ' + CAST( @ErrorSource AS VARCHAR(MAX) )  
  + ' on line ' + CAST( @ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(MAX) )   
  + '. Error: ' + @ErrorMessage;  

BEGIN TRY  

   INSERT INTO Errors(  
      ParentId  
      , ErrorSourceType  
      , ErrorSource  
      , [Message]  
      , [LineNo]  
      , Severity  
      , Stacktrace  
      , ts)  
   VALUES (@ParentErrorId  
      , @ErrorSourceType --@ErrorSourceType --- NOTE: move this into a parameter ...   
      , @ErrorSource  
      , @ComposedErrorMessage  
      , @ErrorLine  
      , @ErrorState  
      , @Stacktrace  
      , GETDATE()  
      );  

  SET @ReturnErrorId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();  

END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  

   RAISERROR( 'An error has occurred but there is no error to log.', 11, 1 );  

END CATCH;
```

I don't know if maybe there is a way to get a snapshot of what's going on the database at a specific time when a certain procedure is called ... I'm not sure how to determine if something isn't happening when it should? Are there any tools that I can make use of or sql features that I don't know about???

Comment: Don't mix and match your error handling process.  If you use `TRY...CATCH` then you don't need the `IF` check for `@@ERROR` and `@@TRANCOUNT` - if there's an error it'll skip right to your `CATCH`.

Comment: If it's me, I would start by logging start and stop for your update and insert steps individually.  You can then easily compare to see if you ever started but didn't stop, or skipped a step.

Comment: The logging start and stop is not a bad idea actually ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor the database, SQL Profiler is a good place to start but it is going to be deprecated.

Extended events are much more capable and I would suggest reading about those if you are really interested in monitoring what's going on.

As a thought, if your procedure code is using the same data to update the row as it is to insert to the other table, consider using OUTPUT.

```
Update table set col1 = 'value'
OUTPUT inserted.col INTO othertable
Where col3 = stuff
```

[OUTPUT and OUTPUT INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Or if this is for some sort of Audit or Log table, you can use DELETED.col1 
That will be the original value prior to it being updated. Note that INSERTED will return the value that you are updating or inserting, it's just called INSERTED for both.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of Visual Studio, try it.  It allows you to step through stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks ... I have, but the problem is not stepping through the stored procedure its trying to reproduce the error ... or trying to identify the error ... I can't see the error while in the debugger if  I can't reproduce it in any environment but production.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would try is to firstly take a copy of this procedure and comment out the try/catch. I have found that tsql does not raise errors if the error generating code is within a try/catch block - I guess this is the sql equivalent of an exception being handled by the catch clause.

I use a table in my database to keep a permanent record of errors as they occur (a trick I learned doing embedded programming)
The errors table creation code is :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.errors (
id smallint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
errordesc nvarchar (max) NOT NULL,
dateandtime smalldatetime NOT NULL, -- Date and time of last occurance
errorcount int NOT NULL) ;
```

My stored procedure for adding a record into the error table is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE jc_diagnostics.jpwsp0005_adderrordescription( 
    @Errordescription nvarchar( max ))
AS 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE
       @Id smallint = 0 ,
       @Currentcount int = 0;
    IF((@Errordescription IS NULL) OR ( @Errordescription = ''))
        BEGIN
            SET @Errordescription = 'Error description missing';
        END;

    SELECT @Id = ( SELECT TOP ( 1 ) id
                 FROM jc_diagnostics.errors
                 WHERE errordesc = @Errordescription );
    IF(@Id IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Currentcount = (SELECT errorcount
                                   FROM jc_diagnostics.errors
                                   WHERE id = @Id );
        SET @Currentcount = @Currentcount + 1;
        UPDATE jc_diagnostics.errors
        SET errorcount = @Currentcount 
          WHERE id = @Id;

        UPDATE jc_diagnostics.errors
        SET dateandtime = CONVERT(smalldatetime , GETDATE())
          WHERE id = @Id;
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        --new entry
        INSERT INTO jc_diagnostics.errors( errordesc ,
                                           dateandtime ,
                                           errorcount )
        VALUES( @Errordescription ,
                CONVERT(smalldatetime , GETDATE()) ,
                1 );
    END;
IF(@Id IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY( );
    END;

RETURN @Id;
END;
```

The calling code when an error occurs is:

```
Declare @Failuredesc nvarchar(max) = 'Description of error';
EXEC @Retval = jc_diagnostics.jpwsp0005_adderrordescription @Failuredesc;
```

The return value @Retval contains the id of the record in the error table so you can look it up

Finally I would create some code to continuously call your procedure until an error is declared. You can then inspect the error table and see if this throws light on your problem.

Hope this helps.
Jude

Answer (score 0):

Logically thinking - because you declare transaction before these 2 steps, any error would result in rollback of both transactions. So most likely there is no error at all here. I would suggest inspect your queries again as it seems that the problem could be in them rather than anywhere else. Please post the entire code if you like more suggestions.

Regards

Roman